# Add shadow on scoll under header

Tags: css, flexbox, shadow

I have a header like so:

```css
.header-wrapper {
  padding: 32px 24px 0 24px;
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: $color-white;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-wrapper">
  <h2 data-qa="customersTitle" class="header-label">Customers</h2>
</header>
```

The `header-wrapper` class is written like above and **cannot be changed**. It **must have** a `display:flex;` attribute, otherwise some elements break.

What I need is: after scrolling a little bit, a shadow to appear under the header. How can I do that? (If I don't use `display:flex` it works. But i **need** to use it)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: onscroll is a function in js. I don't think it can be done with only CSS. you said it work without display flex? please share that working code and we will fix it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same what `@Fuzion` did but with vanilla Js.
adding `eventListener` on the window. which gives us `scrollY` value every time the user scrolls.

checking if `scrollY` is `greater` then `10` `add` my `class` of `shadow` if not `remove` my class of `shadow`

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  let scroll = this.scrollY;
  if (scroll > 10) {
    document.querySelector(".header-wrapper").classList.add("shadow");
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".header-wrapper").classList.remove("shadow");
  }
});
```

```css
.header-wrapper {
  padding: 32px 24px 0 24px;
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 14px 12px -6px grey;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 14px 12px -6px grey;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 12px -6px grey;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-wrapper">
  <h2 data-qa="customersTitle" class="header-label">Customers</h2>
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: bro literally yoinked my answer, yikes.

Comment: you must be joking. lmao.


you are using two functions, two conditional ifs. how is it any similar to yours

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a jQuery scroll function. I have created this as a small little demo, the styling might not be the same as yours, just make sure the classes are correct within the JavaScript!

The shadow will be added once you've scrolled 200px down. If you want to make the scroll distance bigger or smaller you can change the value at `scroll_distance = 100`

Note: I made the header grey just for testing purposes only right now so it's easier to see it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var scroll_distance = 100;

    if (scroll >= scroll_distance) {
      $(".header-wrapper").addClass("one-edge-shadow");
    }
    if (scroll <= scroll_distance) {
      $(".header-wrapper").removeClass("one-edge-shadow");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.header-wrapper {
  padding: 32px 24px 0 24px;
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #eee;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.one-edge-shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 14px 12px -6px grey;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 14px 12px -6px grey;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 12px -6px grey;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header-wrapper">
  <h2 data-qa="customersTitle" class="header-label">Customers</h2>
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have JQuery in my project. It must be done using plain CSS. Thank you tho!

Comment: In that case you should check out this codepen: https://codepen.io/StijnDeWitt/pen/LryNxa, however I have no idea how well this is supported by different browsers.

Comment: Btw you can simply use JQuery inside of your HTML by importing it `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`